# How to integrate Hubspot with custom build CRM (avoiding hubspot UID's)

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-cms

I have a custom built CRM that I would like to integrate with Hubspot. I would like to keep both systems active. At the moment we are manually copying the data from the custom built CRM into Hubspot. I would like to automate this using the Hubspot API.

Do I have to call the Hubspot API using the Hubspot UID's (I don't want to have to add a field in my existing CRM to record the Hubspot UID as that is just moving the existing manual entry to another area).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add an example of the code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

HubSpot's unique identifier for contacts are Contact ID and email address.
So if you already have contacts' email addresses in your non-HubSPot CRM, I believe you would not need Contact ID as the UID to update existing contacts via API.

[Here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/contacts) is the reference:

> An email address is the primary identifier for a contact in HubSpot.
> These endpoints automatically deduplicate email addresses to keep
> HubSpot data clean.

Answer (score 0):

HubSpot API is the way to go https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/overview , however, be sure to read the terms of use to avoid any compliance issue as you will be using their data sources:

https://legal.hubspot.com/developer-terms

Comment: Please add the essential information from the links above into your answer